# Xcode compile times: which Mac configuration delivers noticeable best performance?

Tags: xcode, performance

I looked at the different configurations of Macs available: MacBook Pro, iMac and iMac Pro.

Are the huge configurations of e.g. the iMac Pro (Xeon, 18 cores etc.) noticeable speeding up Xcode compilation times? Or are those specs tailored at video editing?

Also if I compare

- 3,2 GHz 8-Core Intel Xeon W Processor
- 4,2 GHz Quad‑Core Intel Core i7 Processor

more cores, less GHz or the other way round? What's most important for Xcode compilation performance - cores? Processor? Ghz?

Comment: Compilation performance is affected mostly by your code. Your architecture, the number of dependencies between files, the usage of `private`, splitting code to independent modules etc. Better hardware will always help but code architecture will affect build times much more.

Comment: What is your programming language? AFAIR `swift` has/had problems with parrallelizing compilation - only one core was/is used. So it was (and maybe still is) preferable to have a CPU with higher clocks than CPU with more cores.

Answer (score 3):

Its super easy. 
Xcode uses processor power for compiling tasks. 
CPU Specification formula:
**

```
3,2Ghz * 8 cores = 25,6 Ghz
4,2Ghz * 4 cores = 16,8 Ghz
```

**
So answering to your question, the most important for Xcode compilation performance is processor power.
First processor, xeon based will be much more productive for xcode routine. Use that formula.
p.s. My answer based on assumption that both processors is the same or nearnly same year production. Its also important to take in mind the youth of CPU. 
For 100% sure, check your processors at [Geekbench](https://www.geekbench.com/)

Comment: It also uses memory and disk, so why isn't that a factor?

Comment: so according to your calculation, the 3,2GHz/8core should be MUCH faster? Is that calculation really that easy, I mean - would Xcode also make advantage of e.g. 16 or 18 cores?

Comment: @swalkner yes, normally if you choose latest processor which will have more cores and will be more productive using that formula, this processor will beat the race.

Comment: @swift2geek so the two current answers are the exact opposite: I understand this one that the 3.2*8 is much faster, the other answer says the 4.2 outperforms the 3.2...

Comment: It would be super easy if OP used a compiler with good parallelizing abilities. It's not always the case.

Comment: As there are multiple stages in the compilation process, even if each stage was optimised for an unlimited number of cores, the full benefit of all the cores can't be achieved, which lowers the ’total’ clock speed. There will be wasted/redundant cores.

Comment: Your answer presumes that the compilation can be broken into as many processes as cores are available, and that these processes can be executed concurrently to nearly 100%. **Why should this be the case?** As long as you do not answer this, sorry, I think your answer belongs to „Every complex problem has a super easy answer, which is wrong“.

Answer (score 0):

A higher clock speed allows more processes to be executed in a given time frame. Whereas multiple cores allow for parallel processing. However, the benefits are not double, because not everything will be able to run in parallel for the whole time.

4 cores sounds like plenty. You could maybe go to 6 and be able to justify it, but 8 would be overkill and a waste of money. A higher clock speed will be much more useful and would be much more useful when using the computer for other tasks as well. Also, in regards to the type of processor, they don’t matter too much. As long as you are getting the performance, the implementation doesn’t matter much compared to the other metrics.

**Edit**

It is also important to take into account the Turbo Boost speeds. This allows a processor to run at a lower clock speed, when non-intensive tasks are running, in order to save energy consumption. For intensive tasks, it will be the Turbo Boost speed that you are getting. This is managed automatically by macOS, but can be manually controlled using an app such as [Turbo Boost Switcher](http://www.rugarciap.com/turbo-boost-switcher-for-os-x/).

For the Quad-Core i7, it has a Turbo Boost of 4.5GHz, whereas the 8 Core Xeon has a Turbo Boost of 4.2GHz. This makes them much closer in terms of clock speed. However, the i7 still beats the Xeon in terms of outright clock speed. It also beats it in terms of normal speed, which will benefit with other tasks performed on the computer, and will help with any ‘turbo lag’, if it it managed by the system. Finally, it also has an additional benefit of beating the Xeon on price. This means that for compiling and other Xcode tasks, the i7 is a clear winner.

Comment: so this would speak for the '4.2 GHz Quad Core'?

Comment: @swalkner Compared to the 3.2GHz 8 Core Xeon, yes

Answer (score 0):

Look at your current machine. Open Activity Monitor while you are building. If everything is perfect, you would have 100% CPU usage. On a good day you come to 70%, because nothing is perfect.

I have some third party build-scripts that are highly inefficient and use only one core. So your 18 core Mac won't benefit from that at all.

The first and cheapest approach is to make sure you use pre-compiled headers, especially for C++ code, and that your build scripts use all available processors. I have one C++ library that I could build four times faster after doing that.

Note that "GHz" numbers don't tell you what really happens. As your Mac uses more cores, it heats up, and has to reduce the clock speed. So that 3.2 GHz eight core model can run four threads at a much higher speed, probably the same speed as the 4.2 GHz quad core model.

Right now I would recommend you get an M1 Mac for highest single core performance and good multi-core performance, or wait a little bit for their second generation with 8 performance cores. That's what I will be doing.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you take the i7 one. (If both of the processors have the same release date, always take the newer release date)

If you are comparing processor performances, you need to know what that processor build for. Intel Xeon is a server processor, and Intel i7 is high-end pc processor.

When comparing 4,2 GHz Quad‑Core Intel Core i7 Processor vs 3,2 GHz 8-Core Intel Xeon W Processor for a single app the answer is simply the i7 one. Xcode build process may only take one full core with paralleling some its computing process in other core.

The 8-Core Xeon will better use for running computing process as a server do.